ESlint и AirBnb
Пытаюсь настроить конфиг для ESlint с правилами от AirBnb. Eslint перешёл на новую версию, а AirBnb свой пакет не торопится переводить на новые рельсы как я понял.
Линтер сейчас подразумевает использование файла eslint.config.js, в то время как пакет от AirBnb написан для .eslintrc.
У линтера есть статья по их утилитам совместимости
https://eslint.org/blog/2024/05/eslint-compatibility-utilities/#using-with-flatcompat
Но тем не менее каждый раз при попытке запустить проверку js файла я получаю ошибку, что чего-то не работает или что-то не найдено.
Это базовый конфиг от линтера, как я могу интегрировать в него AirBnb по новым правилам?
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";


export default [
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
];

